# Prime divisors of $x^2 − 8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that prime divisors of $x^2 − 8$ for odd x must be of the form 8k ± 1.

I am momentarily studying the quadratic residues, but I didn't seem to know how to approach this one.

Comment: If $p|x^2 - 8$, then 8 is a residue mod p and use quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: $x^2\equiv 8\pmod{p}\iff \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\equiv 2\pmod{p}$ ($x$ is odd, so $p$ is odd and the evuivalences are equivalent). Now, you can't use Quadratic reciprocity directly, since $2$ is not an odd prime. But you can use [Gauss' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28number_theory%29#Applications) to prove that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1\iff p\equiv \pm 1\pmod {8}$ (or equivalently that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}$).

Comment: @Asvin No, Quadratic reciprocity can only be used for odd primes.

Comment: How did you relate it directly with the Gauss' Lemma? I did not get this part. @user31415

Comment: @user31415 The case 2 in quadratic reciprocity is often called the second supplementary law and is generally considered to part of it's statement.